# Add <span> tags to div using Javascript

Tags: javascript

There are quite a few similar questions, but none are quite what I need nor can I fiddle them around to fit what I'm trying to do.

I have the following:

```
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'Hi ' + name;
```

And would like to, somehow, add the `<span>` tags around `name` using the above. I'm attempting to create a simple chat AI for fun, and want to be able to hightlight certain words that the AI is saying.

Comment: is this what you want? `document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'Hi <span>' + name + "</span>";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the spans in your string:

```
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'Hi <span>' + name + '</span>';
```

Comment: Ohhh okay, I was adding them as separate tags, not inside the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can also try 
by storing the node and append the child .

```js
       var First;
       First=document.getElementById("basic").value;
       var v = document.createElement("p");
       v.appendChild(document.createTextNode(First));
       document.getElementById("fd").appendChild(v);
```

Comment: This is the right question when i am wanting to do some programmatically adding...

Comment: In shorter, this also works: `var edv=document.getElementById("plot"); var edp=document.createElement("span"); edv.appendChild(edp); edp.innerHTML="Hello world";`

Answer (score 1):

If you want some programatically, if you are looking for some span simply appearing in the screen:

```
var esp=document.createElement("span");
document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(esp);
esp.innerHTML="This is my span";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it programmatically, create your span using JS.

```
var name = 'Asteria';
var x = document.createElement('span');
x.id = 'highlight';
x.innerText = name;

document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = 'Hi ' + x.outerHTML;
```

and you can use CSS to highlight the span with ID using

```
#highlight { color: red; }
```

Hope this helps.